# object oriented php code Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
// connection.php file 

<?php


class Connection{

   private $host;
   private $username;
   private $password;
   private $database;

   public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$database)
   {
     try{
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     return $conn;
     }catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        return $e->getMessage();
     }
   }

}

?>

// user.php

<?php

class Users extends Connection{

  private $username;
  private $email;
  private $password;

  public function __construct($username,$email,$password){

    $this->username=$username;
    $this->email=$email;
    $this->password=$password;

  }

  public function addUser(){
    $conn = new Connection("localhost","root","","userdata");
    echo "database connection established";
    die();
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO information (UserName, Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $conn->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $password);
    $username=this->username;
    $password=this->password;
    $email=this->email;
    $sql->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";

    $sql->close();
    $conn->close();

  }
}

?>

process.php

<?php

include('lib/connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
  $user = new User("Gautam","gautam@mail.com","123456");
  $user->addUser();
}

?>
```

So the Problem when i try to execute the process.php file the records are not added to the database.So i have created connection class separately where i have written the logic for database connection then i inherited that class to the users where i added the users to the database then i called the object of user class in process.php but records are not added to the database.Please clarify what is the problem associated with it.

Comment: Can you add this error message?

Comment: Show the implementation of `bind_param` method.

Comment: "Please clarify what is the problem" indeed.

Comment: this code is not running i am unable to add users to the database

Comment: Yes, but if it's not running, it show error. We need this error to help you.

Comment: may because of this line echo "database connection established";
    die();  remove this die();

Comment: @GeekyGautam: What do your PHP logs tell you?  When you enable error reporting, is there an error on the page?  When you debug, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: first of all use $this instead of this in your class and second you are call wrong class name User, It is Users, please modify and try this should work.

Comment: One thing you need to know is that PDO does not have `bind_param()` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you did not bind any parameters before executing.

check these lines :

```
$sql = $conn->prepare()
$conn->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $password);
```

this line should be `$sql->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $password);`

and also note that PDO does not have `bind_param()` function it have : `bindParam()`

therefore you need

```
    $sql->bindParam(1, $this->username);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $this->email);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $this->password);
```

This code below should work :

```
<?php

class Users extends Connection
{

    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($username, $email, $password)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email    = $email;
        $this->password = $password;

    }

    public function addUser()
    {
        $conn = new Connection("localhost", "root", "", "userdata");
        echo "database connection established";

        $username = $this->username;
        $password = $this->password;
        $email    = $this->email;



        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO information (UserName, Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")->execute(array($username,$email,$password));

        if (!$sql) {

            print_r("error : " . $conn->errorInfo());
        } else {

            echo "New records created successfully";
        }
        $sql->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}

?>
```

> PS: Don't store passwords in plain text, use php builtin function such
>   as `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to prepare your password.

Answer (score -1):

first of all use $this instead of this in your class and second you call wrong class name User, It is Users, please modify and try, should work.

```
$user = new Users("Gautam","gautam@mail.com","123456");
```

And in your adduser function of class Users

```
$username=$this->username;
$password=$this->password;
$email=$this->email;
```

change as above and it should work..

Comment: Also one more thing, put this line in condition like echo "database onnection established";  die();